# Webdriver focus event : js.executeScript ("document.getElementByName(' ').focus()");

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on an application that **does not contain id attribute for few textboxes** .Other txtboxes have id.If I don't use the **focus event** I'm not able to use **'sendKeys'** for setting the values for textboxes.
Hence I used

```
js.executeScript ("document.getElementById('x').focus()");
```

But since some textboxes don't  have an id attribute i can't use the above hence tried using

```
js.executeScript ("document.getElementByName('xyz').focus()");
```

Ondoing this following exception msg is generated:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementByName is not a function (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a `getElementByName`. You need to do `getElementsByName` (note the 's' for Elements).

`getElementsByName` returns a collection, so you will need to specify the index:

```
js.executeScript ("document.getElementsByName('xyz')[0].focus()");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try clicking on element to set focus.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("someName")).click();
```